# Different time of execution for the same request

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm using `hibernate`, `spring-data-jpa` and `querydsl` .

When I first connect to my index page I manually count the query time of all my `repository.findXXX()` statements. These usually amount to around **5  seconds**,  but when I refresh the page they only take **1 second** to run.

Can somebody explain that difference?

Comment: Verify the components being initialized during first access of your index page. One of them could be the connection pool. Enable debug level logs.

Comment: can you explain more , what's the role of connection pool ?

Comment: looked in the log? seemingly not

Comment: A connection pool is to optimize database access in the application.  More details here - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e10788/intro.htm#BABHFGCA Look into your hibernate_cfg.xml if it is configured

Comment: `<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">` is this a pool connexion ?

Comment: Yes it is a connection pool. Will you accept my answer?

Comment: Yes but just add the connection pool to your answer

Comment: But the connection pool has nothing to do with your issue. The CP is initialized when the app starts up. If you were not using CP than all operations would take longer, not just the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Most likely the database has cached your query, so it runs faster the second time.
2. For Hibernate to cache your query you'd need to:

   - setup 2nd level cache with query caching:

     ```
     <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
     ```
   - activate query cache for the current running query:****

     ```
      List cats = session.createQuery("from MyEntity")
       .setCacheable(true)
       .list();
     ```

Comment: the database (`mysql`) or hibernate cached my query  ?

Comment: Most likely the database. For Hibernate to cache your query you need to activate 2nd level cache, the query cache and mark the query as cacheable.